# Given $x,y\in G$ and $x\neq e$, $|y|=2$ and $yxy^{-1}=x^2$ then find $|x|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> **Question**: Let $x$, $y$ belong to a group $G$. Assume $x\neq e$, $|y|=2$ and $yxy^{-1}=x^2$ then find $|x|$

**My attempt**:

I know that  $|yxy^{-1}|=|x|$ so by given condition I have $|x|=|x^2|$. Further $(yxy^{-1})^k=yx^ky^{-1}$. Is $|x|$ infinite?

Please Help.

Comment: You need to use the condition $|y| = 2$ somewhere!  Stare at the equation $yxy^{-1} = x^2$ and try to *do something* with it that will bring in $y^2$. You already write what happens if you raise $yxy^{-1}$ to a power, but that's not quite what you should do since it doesn't let you bring in $y^2$.

Comment: @KCd sir, please can you help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$y^2xy^{-2}=y(yxy^{-1})y^{-1}=yx^2y^{-1}=(yxy^{-1})^2=x^4$

Also, $y^2xy^{-2}=exe=x$ .

Therefore $x^4=x$ and $x^3=e$. Since $x\ne e$ the order of $x$ is $3$.

Answer (score 2):

No, the order of $x$ need not be infinite. Take the dihedral group
$$
D_3=\langle x,y\mid x^3=e,y^2=e,xy=yx^2\rangle.
$$
We have $y=y^{-1}$ so that $yxy^{-1}=x^2$ and $y$ has order $2$, whereas $x$ has order $3$.

Comment: Sir then how to find $|x|$

Comment: sir i had checked again. It is same. Question is from Contemporary abstract algebra by Gallian 4th edition. Supplimentary exercises for chapter 1-4