# Given that $x,y\in G$ and $xyx^{-1}=y^{17}$. Find order of $y$ if $ |x|=2$, order of $y$ is odd and $y\neq e$

Tags: group-theory

My aim is to somehow get powers in multiple of 3 so that finally I get $y^{n}=e$ and eliminate x.
So I tried to get $xy^{3}x^{-1}=y^{51}$ and I am also aware of the result that order of $xyx^{-1}$ is same as order of $y$. But I am not able to proceed further. Please give some hints. Similar question is here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3513615/given-x-y-in-g-and-x-neq-e-y-2-and-yxy-1-x2-then-find-x) but I am not able to use it to my advantage

Comment: Please don't change questions that have been correctly answered.

Comment: @DerekHoltpoint noted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $x^2=e,$

$$y=x^2y(x^2)^{-1}=x(xyx^{-1})x^{-1}=xy^{17}x^{-1}=(xyx^{-1})^{17}=(y^{17})^{17}=y^{289}$$

So, $y^{288}=e$.

Since $288=2^43^2$, order of $y$ must be **$3$ or $9$**.

**Append**

$3$, $9$ can both be an answer, because for all $n$, there exists $x,y\in D_n$(Dihedral group) such that $xyx^{-1}=y^{n-1}$.

Comment: I have typed the Question incorrectly. Order of x is 3 instead of 2. (I have Edited) Thanks for the approach. I believe its the same